# What is the meaning of the symbols on the Arrowhead in the season 3 intro?

Tags: analysis, reference, arrow, arrowverse, title-sequence

In the Arrow season 3 starting and ending intro, the Arrowhead got changed from plain to thicker one with symbols embodied on it, as depicted below

[image]

Is there any deep meaning/symbolism behind those symbols or is it just for styling?

Comment: no confirmation on this yet, but my gut says they're supposed to represent something vaguely-Arabic-ish-looking because of the whole Ra's al'Ghul storyline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a nod to the later episodes, The arrowhead was similar to the stencil used for branding him by Ra's al Ghul , below is the side by side comparison:

[image]

There were instances in season 3 where the logo got changed to something else:

> In season 3 episode 7 "Draw Back Your bow" the title arrowhead logo
>   was that of Cupid's heart shape arrow. In season 3 episode 8 "The
>   Brave and The Bold" Lightning was added to the logo as the Flash guest
>   starred. In season 3 episode 14 "The Return" the arrowhead logo
>   reverted to the season 2 arrowhead when Slade Wilson returned. -
>   [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193021/trivia)

This trend was continued for the 4th season

> with new arrowhead logo resembling his new superhero name:
>  **Green Arrow** [image] Except for flash crossover.